# Actionscript 3.0 any way to give the mouse click holding function continously?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have huge number have to click.
but **MouseEvent.CLICK** only can do once per click.
Any other way to give the mouse click holding and the function are repeating ?

Comment: enhance your question: what have you tried in as3? what are you thinking in pseudo code?

Comment: i doing a oven, the button is actually increasing the time, i have 3 text field for hour,minute and second.But, now i using MOUSE.CLICK it is too slow.So, i wish have a mouse click holding function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

1. On `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`, create an interval to fire the method bound to `MouseEvent.CLICK`
2. On `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP`, clear the interval

Here's some *untested* code (that reads in English pretty well):

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

var displayObject:DisplayObject = new DisplayObject(); // the existing object that is clickable, i'm only instantiating for the purpose of this demo
displayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(e:MouseEvent) { // again the click handler for illustrative purposes
    trace(getTimer().toString(10)+': clicked!');
}):

// here is the flow i'm talking about
var interval:Timer = new Timer(1000/stage.frameRate);
interval.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,triggerClick);

displayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOWN,startRepeatClick);
displayObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.UP,stopRepeatClick);

function startRepeatClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    interval.start();
}

function stopRepeatClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    interval.stop();
}

function triggerClick(e:TimerEvent) {
    var clickEvent:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK,true,false,displayObject.mouseX,displayObject.mouseY);
    displayObject.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
```